# Postgres count values in json column

Tags: postgresql

I have a column of json arrays, and I need to produce counts of the values inside the arrays

so if my data looks like

```
["1", "2"]
["1", "2"]
["1", "2", "3"]
["1"]
["2"]
["2"]
```

I need to produce something like

```
{"1" => 4, "2" => 5, "3" => 1}
```

Is this kind of aggregation possible in Postgres? I'm honestly not sure where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) to turn the array into a SETOF (rows of output). Then just aggregate normally.

```
testdb=# with input_data as (select '["1", "1", "2"]'::jsonb j)
SELECT elem, count(elem)
FROM input_data, jsonb_array_elements(input_data.j) AS elem
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
 elem | count 
------+-------
 "1"  |     2
 "2"  |     1
(2 rows)
```